# PayPal client-side? What is minimum code required for multiple buttons?

Tags: paypal

I'm working with .Net, trying to implement multiple buttons.

I'm getting an answer from PayPal (payment id, payer-id, etc.), but everything is client-side. How can I check the payment on server-side?

Do I need to implement all this code for each button?

```
<script>
paypal.Button.render({

    env: 'production', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

    client: {
        sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
        production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    },

    payment: function() {

        var env    = this.props.env;
        var client = this.props.client;

        return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                }
            ]
        });
    },

    commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

        // Optional: display a confirmation page here

        return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
            // Show a success page to the buyer
        });
    }

}, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To get the information on the server side, you can pass `data.paymentID` to your server side and use it to make a REST call to paypal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/show-payment-details/

  - To render multiple buttons you do need to call `paypal.Button.render()` multiple times, but if you need to you can do this in a for loop, or something.